# Forward fill dataframe column if string is present in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I want to forward fill one of the columns but only if the string is present in one of the other columns.

```
       Type                                                 Match     Matchup
0    Parent  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_NYY-vs-LAA  NYY-vs-LAA
1     Child  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_NYY-vs-LAA         NaN
2  SubChild  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_NYM-vs-LAD  NYM-vs-LAD
3  SubChild  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_NYM-vs-LAD         NaN
4      Test                                All_Star_Game_12252000         NaN
5     Child  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_BAL-vs-BOS  BAL-vs-BOS
6    Parent  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_BAL-vs-BOS         NaN
7     Child  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_TBR-vs-COL  TBR-vs-COL
8    Parent  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_TBR-vs-COL         NaN
9  SubChild  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_TBR-vs-COL         NaN
```

For example, if `Matchup` is present `Match`, I want to forward fill it so that the output looks like:

```
    Type                                                   Match       Matchup
  Parent    ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_NYY-vs-LAA    NYY-vs-LAA
   Child    ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_NYY-vs-LAA    NYY-vs-LAA
SubChild    ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_NYM-vs-LAD    NYM-vs-LAD
SubChild    ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_NYM-vs-LAD    NYM-vs-LAD
    Test                                  All_Star_Game_12252000    
   Child    ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_BAL-vs-BOS    BAL-vs-BOS
  Parent    ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_BAL-vs-BOS    BAL-vs-BOS
   Child    ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_TBR-vs-COL    TBR-vs-COL
  Parent    ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_TBR-vs-COL    TBR-vs-COL
SubChild    ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_TBR-vs-COL    TBR-vs-COL
```

Comment: `df.groupby('Match')['Matchup'].ffill()`?

Comment: `NSH-vs-NYC` isn't present in `ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_NYY-vs-LAA` though...

Comment: Should the value of `Matchup` in the first frame be `NYY-vs-LAA`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stealing @mozway's comment

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO("""
       Type                                                 Match     Matchup
0    Parent  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_NYY-vs-LAA  NYY-vs-LAA
1     Child  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_NYY-vs-LAA         NaN
2  SubChild  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_NYM-vs-LAD  NYM-vs-LAD
3  SubChild  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_NYM-vs-LAD         NaN
4      Test                                All_Star_Game_12252000         NaN
5     Child  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_BAL-vs-BOS  BAL-vs-BOS
6    Parent  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_BAL-vs-BOS         NaN
7     Child  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_TBR-vs-COL  TBR-vs-COL
8    Parent  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_TBR-vs-COL         NaN
9  SubChild  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_TBR-vs-COL         NaN
"""),
    sep="\s+"
)

df.update(df.groupby("Match")["Matchup"].ffill())

print(df)
```

```
       Type                                                 Match     Matchup
0    Parent  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_NYY-vs-LAA  NYY-vs-LAA
1     Child  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_NYY-vs-LAA  NYY-vs-LAA
2  SubChild  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_NYM-vs-LAD  NYM-vs-LAD
3  SubChild  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_NYM-vs-LAD  NYM-vs-LAD
4      Test                                All_Star_Game_12252000         NaN
5     Child  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_BAL-vs-BOS  BAL-vs-BOS
6    Parent  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_BAL-vs-BOS  BAL-vs-BOS
7     Child  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_TBR-vs-COL  TBR-vs-COL
8    Parent  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_TBR-vs-COL  TBR-vs-COL
9  SubChild  ABC_12252000_NY_Leag_Natl_en-NY_RegSeason_TBR-vs-COL  TBR-vs-COL
```

References

- [`pd.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)
- [`pd.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
- [`pd.Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html)
- [`pd.SeriesGroupBy.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.ffill.html)